# Forbidden error connecting to WMS with QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

**FR** :

> j'essaie de me connecter à un service WMS
>   `http://geod-prod-ws.cg94.loc/WMS_ASSAIN_DSEA/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`
>   mais ça bloque

[image: Erreur WMS]

> Par contre ça fonctionne sous MapInfo ! Avez vous une idée d'ou cela
>   peut provenir ?

---

**EN** :

I try to connect to a WMS service :

`http://geod-prod-ws.cg94.loc/WMS_ASSAIN_DSEA/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`

but it blocks, but it works under Mapinfo!

Do you have any idea where this might come from?

Comment: Please use an online translation service in order to post your question in English, thank you.

Comment: And if you try without the last part : `http://geod-prod-ws.cg94.loc/WMS_ASSAIN_DSEA/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMS` ?

Comment: Is this a local server?

Comment: yes it's a local server, don't work J.Monticolo

Comment: "Server replied: Forbidden". Did you try adding login credentials to your query?

Comment: The endpoint should be just `http://geod-prod-ws.cg94.loc/WMS_ASSAIN_DSEA/service.svc/get?` no WMS parameters

Comment: What actual request is sent by QGIS to the WMS server, you can use Fiddler, or the QGIS Network logger, to discover it.  Can you perhaps post the response of the `http://geod-prod-ws.cg94.loc/WMS_ASSAIN_DSEA/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&` request if you make it in a browser.

Comment: Yes nmtoken in IE it's work !

Comment: Yes, but can you post the XML response as an [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/353541/edit) to your question.    We can guess the issue is not authentication, so possibly there is some other issue.  Is the same URL used inside the response for example?